# ESP8266-01 is not working and it's hot

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

it has been so long since I tried to connect the esp8266 through Arduino Uno and get it to work my goal is to send data from the Arduino Uno to web site, I have tried everything and a lot of codes but none worked at first I could get a response  but sometimes it does and sometimes it does not I even bought an other one but the new one did not respond at all so I flashed the old one following the instructions in [here](http://remotexy.com/en/help/esp8266-firmware-update/) and I got response the next day I tried to reuse it and it does not respond at all not even when I put the serial on 115200 and both NR&CR and tried AT but nothing showed in return .i found this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cjufbgOBYo)
and I tried to get it to work using a mobile app but as usual, it does not work

```
AT
AT+RST
ATE0
AT+CWMODE=1
AT+CWQAP
AT+CWDHCP=1,1
AT+CWJAP="RemoteXY","12345678"
```

but i did not get hte name of it wifi in my wifi list
this is the code

```
// RemoteXY select connection mode and include library  
#define REMOTEXY_MODE__ESP8266_HARDSERIAL

#include <RemoteXY.h> 

// RemoteXY connection settings  
#define REMOTEXY_SERIAL Serial 
#define REMOTEXY_SERIAL_SPEED 115200 
#define REMOTEXY_WIFI_SSID "RemoteXY" 
#define REMOTEXY_WIFI_PASSWORD "12345678" 
#define REMOTEXY_SERVER_PORT 6377 


// RemoteXY configurate   
#pragma pack(push, 1) 
uint8_t RemoteXY_CONF[] = 
  { 255,2,0,0,0,30,0,8,13,0,
  2,0,70,25,22,11,2,26,31,31,
  79,78,0,79,70,70,0,1,0,10,
  26,12,12,2,31,88,0 }; 

// this structure defines all the variables of your control interface  
struct { 

    // input variable
  uint8_t switch_1; // =1 if switch ON and =0 if OFF 
  uint8_t button_1; // =1 if button pressed, else =0 

    // other variable
  uint8_t connect_flag;  // =1 if wire connected, else =0 

} RemoteXY; 
#pragma pack(pop) 

///////////////////////////////////////////// 
//           END RemoteXY include          // 
///////////////////////////////////////////// 

#define PIN_SWITCH_1 2
#define PIN_BUTTON_1 12


void setup()  
{ 
  RemoteXY_Init ();  

  pinMode (PIN_SWITCH_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PIN_BUTTON_1, OUTPUT);

  // TODO you setup code 

} 

void loop()  
{  
  RemoteXY_Handler (); 

  digitalWrite(PIN_SWITCH_1, (RemoteXY.switch_1==0)?LOW:HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_1, (RemoteXY.button_1==0)?LOW:HIGH);

  // TODO you loop code 
  // use the RemoteXY structure for data transfer 


}
```

i wired it like this

[image]
one last thing is it gets hot every time so what could be the problem what's wrong with is what should I do

Comment: Sounds like it's dead, Jim.

Comment: both, even the new one ?

Comment: Hit is not good. Maybe there is something fundamentally wrong that you are doing to them.

Comment: like what i connected the RX -> RX /TX-> TX/ CH_en and vcc to 3.3 v of the arduino / gnd ->gnd

Comment: Well yes, that's something fundamentally wrong. Connect RX to TX and TX to RX instead.

Comment: I tried that too I even tried to connect them to other arduino pins

Comment: It's probably already dead. It's too late to try changing things now.

Comment: Also you omitted the resistors for your LEDs. You're well on the way to killing the Arduino too.

Comment: but i tried to flash it and tried the at and responded yes then i tried at+rst and responded error but then i tried AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0 i  then it does not respond at all again .i did not put the leds was trying it with without

Answer (score 3):

when a chip gets hot as soon as the VCC/GND is connected, it means :

1. **The VCC/GND are internally connected due to a previous failure** (it
   gets hot AFTER the accident).
2. **An output pin, is connected to a supply rail through a very low resistance load (or short circuited).** pins usually sink or
   source as low as 20mA of current. so if you connect them to a load
   less than (3.3/20)*1000 ~= 150 ohms (in your case with 3.3v supply),
   you are going to fry the output driver. always be sure that a pin, even if it's defined as an input, has a little resistor (a 220 ohms res).
   this accident happens between output/supply or output/output pins.

you may have misconnected TX pin to a wrong pin.

Comment: i have connected to tx the TX of the arduino in this example .how do i know if it is working

Comment: @ElaHidri you mean TX to RX right ? TX line connects to RX line of the other end

Comment: yes I even tried other Arduino pins .do I need to add level shifter?

Comment: no you don't need a level shifter for ESP8266 and Arduino as the esp pins are 5v tolerant. but it you connect TX to another "output" pin you may have damaged them. TX pin is an output, idle high pin. another output pin with idle low, short circuits the pins @ElaHidri

Comment: @ElaHidri even though people seem to successfully do so, by the official specs the esp8266 is not 5V tolerant. You supply the esp with 3.3V at vcc, so connecting any pin to a 5v logic level directly is incorrect.